# website hosted on Firebase Hosting is not opening Flutter app through deep links

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, firebase-hosting, ios-universal-links

I am currently implementing the deep linking feature. I have followed [Flutter official documentation][1] but it is not working for me.

I have hosted a static website with the required files using Firebase Hosting under this path

```
public/.well-known/assetlinks.json
public/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

assetlinks.json

```
[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.company.appName",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["sha256takenFromGooglePlayConsole"]
    }
  }]
```

apple-app-site-association

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
      {
        "appID": "teamID.com.company.appName",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

assetlinks.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also tried putting

```
  "appAssociation": "NONE"
```

but it did not work.

I tried this command to test the logic of handling the deep links

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://<web-domain>/details"' \
    <package name>
```

and it worked perfectly.

I am assuming that the issue is with the Hosting, any idea what might be the issue? I would really appreciate your help!